# table1() Output Labeling all Data as "Missing"

Tags: r

I am trying to make a descriptive statistics table in R and my code functions properly (producing a table) but despite the fact that I have no missing values in my dataset, the table outputs all of my values as missing. I am still a novice in R, so I do not have a broad enough knowledge base to troubleshoot.

My code:

```
data <-  read_excel("Data.xlsx")
```

```
 data$stage <-
   factor(data$stage, levels=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
          labels =c("Stage 0", "Stage 1", "Stage 2", "Stage 3", "Unsure", "Unsure (Early Stage)", "Unsure (Late Stage"))
 data$primary_language <-factor(data$primary_language, levels=c(1,2), labels = c("Spanish", "English"))
data$status_zipcode <- factor(data$status_zipcode, levels = (1:3), labels = c("Minority", "Majority", "Diverse"))
data$status_censusblock <- factor(data$status_censusblock, levels = c(0:2), labels = c("Minority", "Majority", "Diverse"))
data$self_identity <- factor(data$self_identity, levels = c(0:1), labels = c("Hispanic/Latina","White/Caucasian"))
data$subjective_identity <- factor(data$subjective_identity, levels = c(0,1,2,4), labels = c("Hispanic/Latina", "White/Caucasian", "Multiracial", "Asian"))

label (data$stage)<- "Stage at Diagnosis"
label(data$age)  <- "Age"
label(data$primary_language) <- "Primary language"
label(data$status_zipcode)<- "Demographic Status in Zipcode Area"
label(data$status_censusblock)<- "Demographic Status in Census Block Group"
label(data$self_identity) <- "Self-Identified Racial/Ethnic Group"
label(data$subjective_identity)<- "Racial/Ethnic Group as Identified by Others"

table1(~ stage +age + primary_language + status_zipcode + status_censusblock + self_identity + subjective_identity| primary_language, data=data)
```

Table output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nf0E2.png)

Data set:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05QAr.png)

Answer (score 0):

When I run the data set the values are there. It actually worked for me when I re-did the spacing:

```
data$stage <- factor(data$stage, 
levels = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
labels = c("Stage 0", "Stage 1", "Stage 2", "Stage 3", "Unsure", "Unsure (Early Stage)", "Unsure (Late Stage"))
```

When I did it exactly as you typed it came up with NA's, too. Try the first and see if it works for you that way. Then check the spacing for the others. That may be all it is.

I do end up with one NA on the stage column because 0 is not defined in your  levels.

Edit: Ran the rest so here are some other points.

You end up with an NA in stage because one of your values is 0 but it's not defined with a label

You end up with NA's in language because you have a 0 and a 1 but you define it as 1, 2. So you'd need to change to the values. You end up with NA's in other portions because of the :

Change your code to this and you should have the values you need except that initial 0 in "stage":

```
data$stage <- factor(data$stage, 
levels=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
labels =c("Stage 0", "Stage 1", "Stage 2", "Stage 3", "Unsure", "Unsure (Early Stage)", "Unsure (Late Stage"))
data$primary_language <-factor(data$primary_language, 
levels=c(0,1), 
labels = c("Spanish", "English"))
data$status_zipcode <- factor(data$status_zipcode, 
levels = c(0,1,2), 
labels = c("Minority", "Majority", "Diverse"))
data$status_censusblock <- factor(data$status_censusblock, 
levels = c(0,1,2), 
labels = c("Minority", "Majority", "Diverse"))
data$self_identity <- factor(data$self_identity, 
levels = c(0,1), 
labels = c("Hispanic/Latina","White/Caucasian"))
data$subjective_identity <- factor(data$subjective_identity, 
levels = c(0,1,2,4), 
labels = c("Hispanic/Latina", "White/Caucasian", "Multiracial", "Asian"))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snU3I.png)

[image: UpdatedOutput_12_16]

Comment: If that doesn't work, let me know. I just go with step by step to check that the data is changed as I wanted

Comment: Thank you, Kathy :D

Comment: After making your suggested edits, Kathy, I am still producing the same error! See the error I am getting in the description above!

Comment: I updated the syntax in one place because I found an error in what I did on the line for zipcode both on my part and the values (I missed a "c" and also the values are 0, 1, and 2, instead of 1, 2, 3 from your original code. Before I relabel or look at the table not working with values, does your output look like mine in the editing answer?